# Bind dynamic DropDownList in new form (external lists involved)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, jquery, external-list

Short version of the question: I am dynamically building the option list of a `DropDownList` based on a selection from another `DropDownList` with jQuery. How do I bind the new option list so that it will post back to the list?

Details:
I'm using SP2010 and SharePoint Designer The new form is feeding an external list in an SQL db.  A second external list is the dynamic list source.

The user is selecting a location which jQuery uses to create a list of names sourced from the 2nd external list.  Unfortunately, the name selected is not being posted back.  I can hard code the names from SP designer and that posts, but the list generated by jQuery is not posting. I assume this is because jQuery generates the list after `ddwrt:databind` is ran.

Thanks for the help.
KR

Answer (score 0):

In leu of the dynamic dropdown list not posting, here's the workaround with jquery.  I'd still be interested in hearing a better way.

Instead of deleting the original FormField, I enclosed it in a span tag with style=display:none.  Then using jquery I called the selected value and changed the value of the original FormField.

```
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <span id="originalFormField" style="display:none">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Name" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string('')),'@Name')}"/>
    </span>
    <span id="dropdownlist1">
        <SharePoint:DVDropDownList runat="server" id="ddl2{$Pos}">
                <asp:ListItem runat="server" value="0">Please select a name...</asp:ListItem>
        </SharePoint:DVDropDownList>
    </span>
    <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="Name" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>

// JQUERY:
<script type="text/javascript" id="saveName">
        function saveName(){
            var idDDL2 = '#'+$("select[id*='ddl2']").attr("id");
            var idFF2 = '#'+ $("[id*='ff2']").attr("id");
            $(idDDL2).change(function(){
                var value = $(idDDL2+' option:selected').text();
                $("[idFF2]").val(value);
            });
        }
    </script>
```